# Postfix server rejecting sender address

Tags: debian, postfix, dovecot, debian-wheezy

I installed a mailserver (postfix / dovecot) on my Debian Wheezy system and cannot send mails.

Since I just want to administer a mail server and don't have a domain yet, I'm working with the external IP address of the server. Corresponding to the documentation this should work.

**EDIT I:** The user exists and I can authenticate IMAP and SMTP.

**EDIT II:** The MySQL user sender map (as mentioned in comments) returns `user@ip`

The log file shows the error message

```
NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from [...]: 553 5.7.1 <user@ip>: Sender address rejected: not owned by user user@ip; from=<user@ip> to=<user@ip> proto=ESMTP helo=<[192.168.24.10]>
```

The sender address equals the (SASL) login user name, so the error message doesn't seem quite meaningful to me.

I might mention here that I search all over the web and didn't find a solution. I didn't edit the configs much, only enabled smtps in `master.cf` and hosts, IP addresses and mysql maps in the `main.cf`. The remaining is untouched.

What could be my problem here?

Here some config files:

`main.cf`

```
myhostname = mail.fictional-domain.local
resolve_numeric_domain = yes
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = ip, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all

# Authentification
smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth_dovecot
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_ma$
smtpd_sender_login_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_sender_login_maps.cf
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch
        reject_unknown_sender_domain
        reject_unverified_sender
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated
        permit_mynetworks
        reject_unauth_destination
        reject_unknown_reverse_client_hostname
# Virtual mailboxes
#local_transport = virtual
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail/
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_minimum_uid = 104
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_transport = dovecot
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
```

`master.cf`

```
# [removed commented lines]
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -d ${recipient}

smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
# [removed commented lines]
smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
# [removed commented lines]
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
# [removed commented lines]
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
# [removed commented lines]
# [removed commented lines]
pickup    fifo  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
# [removed commented lines]
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
# [removed commented lines]
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
# [removed commented lines]
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
# [removed commented lines]
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
# [removed commented lines]
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -   n   n   -   2   pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
```

`mysql_sender_login_maps.cf`

```
hosts = 127.0.0.1
user = postfix
password = postfixmysqldatabase
dbname = postfixDB
query = SELECT username AS allowedUser FROM mailbox WHERE username="%s" AND active = 1 UNION SELECT goto FROM alias WHERE address="%s" AND active = 1
```

Comment: Can you post your `master.cf`? It sound like there may be some smtpd restrictions in there that are being triggered.

Comment: @squircle: I added the `master.cf` for you. I'm still really new to server administration (although I did WEB server administration in the past) so you might have to explain some things more detailed =)

Comment: Unfortunately, you didn't include much logging information.You should also change your password since you just posted it for the whole internet to see. I have the following questions: 1) Is there a user@ip in your SQL database? 2) Can you actually authenticate as user@ip? 3) Does removing `reject_unverified_sender` and reloading postfix resolve the problem?

Comment: What's the output of command `postmap -q 'user@ip' mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_sender_login_maps.cf`? (this command used to verify that lookup database return the expected value)

Comment: Funny you thought this would be my real MySQL password... Nevertheless you would have to get into my local network to access the DB ;-) 1) YES. 2) YES, IMAP & SMTP. 3) NO. What further logging info would you need? There is just `connect from...`, the error and `disconnect`. `postmap -q [...]` outputs `user@ip`

Comment: Does this info help you helping?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this error, the problem was my

```
smtpd_sender_login_maps =ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-query-file.cf
```

was delivering false value, as a result of my tempering with it.

Hope this'd help